# How to configure double-click word delimiters in Eclipse CDT?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

Colon (:) is not considered a word delimiter when I double-click a word in the Eclipse CDT editor to select it. How do I make double-click selection treat colon as a delimiter?

If the solution is file-type dependent, I need it to work while editing makefiles.

I have found an FAQ about [extending the editor to change double-click selection strategy](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_change_the_selection_on_a_double-click_in_my_editor%3F), but I'm looking for a configuration or plugin solution, which does not require Eclipse development on my part.

At the time of writing, I am using the newest Eclipse CDT:

```
 Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers   1.2.1.20090918-0703 epp.package.cpp
 Eclipse Platform   3.5.1.M20090917-0800    org.eclipse.platform.ide
 EPP CPP Feature    1.2.1.20090918-0703 org.eclipse.epp.package.cpp.feature.feature.group
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure this question should still be open.

Anyway FYI I just tried on the latest `CDT 8.1.1.201209170703` version based on Eclipse Juno, the colon character is working as word delimiter when you double-click on a word.